# filtering a list to store different combinations

Tags: java

I have a list of available hotel rooms

```
List <RoomInventory> inventoryList = new ArrayList<RoomInventory>();
```

There are different types of rooms on the list (Double, Family, Twin, Triple)
each with a price, roomCode, etc..
Each room holds a maximum number of people
I need to show the top 3 cheapest options for a party of 7.
My question is how can I  find and store the different possible room combinations for a party of 7?

this is what I have (Created a new array of different room options to show user)

```
roomOptions roomOption1 = new roomOptions("family", 2);
roomOption1.setRoomType("family");
roomOption1.setNumberOfRooms(2);
roomOptions.add(roomOption1);

roomOptions roomOption2 = new roomOptions("Family room" + "Twin Triple", 2);
roomOption2.setRoomType("family + Twin Triple");
roomOption2.setNumberOfRooms(2);
roomOptions.add(roomOption2);

roomOptions roomOption3 = new roomOptions("Twin Room", 4);
roomOption3.setRoomType("Twin");
roomOption3.setNumberOfRooms(4);
roomOptions.add(roomOption3);

roomOptions roomOption4 = new roomOptions("Double Room" +  "Twin Room", 4);
roomOption4.setRoomType("Double + Twin Room");
roomOption4.setNumberOfRooms(4);
roomOptions.add(roomOption4);

roomOptions roomOption5 = new roomOptions("Family Room" + "Twin Room" + "Double" , 3);
roomOption5.setRoomType("Family Room + Double + Twin Room");
roomOption5.setNumberOfRooms(3);
```

**Is there a more dynamic way of finding the different room combinations that would suit a party of 7 ?**

Comment: Have a Room class. Then have a DoubleRoom that extends that class, FamilyRoom that extends that class... etc. Then do List<Room> roomList = new ArrayList<Room>();

Comment: See the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) - in this case minimizing the cost (instead of maximizing).  Read about the idea/approach/algorithm until you can do a small example **on paper**.  Then translate to code.